# Get cookies in Webdriver how?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a method in Webdriver Ruby bindings for getting the cookies:

```
(Array<Hash>) all_cookies
```

with the following description:

Returns:

```
* (Array<Hash>) — list of cookies
```

Could you please, provide an example of its usage.
Thanks!

Comment: FYI: In .Net it's driver.Manage().Cookies;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.manage.all_cookies
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is nice blog on webdirver and cookies:
http://element34.ca/blog/webdriver-and-cookies

In case you are looking for solution to read cookies from multiple domains:
http://automationoverflow.blogspot.in/2013/07/getting-cookies-from-all-domains.html