# RESTAssured and WebDriver: get and use a session id from browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sessionid

I'm trying to use WebDriver to get the session ID from the browser being tested so that I can pass that ID in through the given().session(string) functionality in RESTAssured.  The browser will go through a normal login to create the session ID.  Any ideas how to capture it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your session id by casting the driver object to RemoteWebDriver like this

`String session = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just read it from cookie. Or I don't understand the problem.

Here is similar problem [Get cookies in Webdriver how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580989/get-cookies-in-webdriver-how)