# Restassured CSRF protection with X-XSRF-TOKEN (like angularjs) header

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, csrf, rest-assured

I'm trying to write a web integration test with restassured spring security authentication. The application uses AngularJS and Spring Boot.
Since I use AngularJS the CSRF protection is done with X-XSRF-TOKEN header and XSRF-TOKEN cookie (as I understand its default for angular).

How can I configure restassured to generated and send this token with form authentication ? Right now I have something like this:

```
given().auth().form("user", "password", new FormAuthConfig("login", "username", "password").sendCsrfTokenAsHeader()).when().get("/index.html").then().log().all().statusCode(200);
```

But in the logs I see that CSRF token is invalid when posting credentials to /login .

Comment: It could be a bug, do you have an example service that I can try out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTAssured and WebDriver: get and use a session id from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366344/restassured-and-webdriver-get-and-use-a-session-id-from-browser)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I have this same question, did a lot of fruitless tinkering, so far.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do 2 `GET` before post to use spring security CSRF protection in your rest client and test class.

1. Make a `GET` request to login. This will return the `JSESSIONID` token and `XSRF-TOKEN` tokens. If you use the returned `XSRF-TOKEN` to `POST` it will fail, because we got it using empty/false `JSESSIONID`.
2. Get a useful `XSRF-TOKEN` from the second `GET`, using `JSESSIONID` from previous request.
3. Now you can use `XSRF-TOKEN` for your `POST`.

Example how to use CSRF protection with `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in rest assured:

```
//1) get sessionId
Response response =
        given().auth().preemptive().basic(userName, userPassword).contentType(JSON).
        when().get(PREFIX_URL + "/users/user").
        then().log().all().extract().response();
String jsessionidId =  response.getSessionId();//or response.cookie("JSESSIONID");

//2) get XSRF-TOKEN using new/real sessionId
response =
        given().
        sessionId(jsessionidId).//or cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionidId).
        contentType(JSON).
        when().get(PREFIX_URL + "/users/user").
        then().log().all().extract().response();

//3) post data using XSRF-TOKEN
given().log().all().
        sessionId(jsessionidId).//or cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionidId).
        header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", response.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")).
        queryParam("pos",pos.getId()).
        queryParam("date",date).
        queryParam("group_id",itemGroup.getId()).
        body(orderItems).
        contentType(JSON).
when().
        post(PREFIX_URL + "/orders/orderitems").
then().
    log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Here it asks for Form param instead of basic aut. Here in your example you are using basic auth but the above question required form param.

Answer (score 1):

Some delay in response but I hope it helps someone

```
Response loginResponse = given().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).
    param(USERNAME, "").
    param(PASSWORD, "").
    when().post(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL).then().log().all().
    extract().response();

given().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).
  cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", loginResponse.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")).
  header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", loginResponse.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")).
  sessionId(loginResponse.getSessionId()).
  when().post(USER_PATH).
  then().log().all().statusCode(CREATED.value());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RestAssured filter to retrieve and inject the token when needed.

Given the server's response to `GET /login` always includes the token cookie. Then a solution which keeps the actual test code clean could look like this:

```java
package com.example;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS;
import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.authentication.FormAuthConfig;
import io.restassured.filter.*;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
public class CsrfSampleTest {

    @BeforeAll
    public void addCsrfCookieFilter() {
        RestAssured.filters(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec,
                    FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
                String csrfToken = requestSpec.getCookies().getValue("XSRF-TOKEN");
                if (csrfToken == null) {
                    csrfToken = RestAssured.given().noFilters().get("/login").cookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
                }
                requestSpec.replaceHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken);
                return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        RestAssured.given()
            .auth().form("user", "password", new FormAuthConfig("login", "username", "password"))
        .when()
            .get("/index.html")
        .then()
            .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```